# What does RoW mean on a Steam pre-purchase?

Tags: steam

I want to pre-purchase some game on Steam, and it lists `Pre-Purchase (RoW)` after the game name. What does that mean? Below is an example:

[image: pic]

Comment: I would guess "Rest of World"... but it looks like you're in the US, so I don't see how that fits...

Comment: @TZHX A lot of Steam users change their region to obscure countries to avoid issues with server overloads. The displayed information probably changes based on region.

Comment: @TZHX I'm not in the US. Other regions pay with US$ as well.

Comment: @DaveMcClelland The content server you chose does not affact the store in any way, since it uses your IP as a basis what to show you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

RoW means "rest of world".  Many games are released in one region first, and then "rest of world" second.

For example, when I look at that game on steam, it says "SPECIAL PROMOTION! Offer ends July 9th."  So my region will get the game first.